# javascript how to set null input equal to 0

Tags: javascript, function, nan

I have javascript function that will calculate the value for "TOTAL" row and "Balance" column in the table. But if there are no input, the javascript will return NaN which is not a number error.
How to set if there are no input in the text box, javascript will interpret it as 0 so that I will not get NaN error.

[image: This is my table]

As you can see, the textbox for pay(notes 50) column are empty. Then value for balance and total become NaN.

Comment: I guess you are probably using `parseInt` or equivalent somewhere. Just add an `if` statement to check if the String is equal to `""` or not (empty string)

Comment: You can use [isNan()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function for checking it or you should convert the inputs to integer using [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: Or change to something like `parseInt(value || 0)` so that it defaults to 0 if value is not a number.

Comment: @nicovank, I've tried parseInt(value || 0) when declaring the variable and managed to parsed the value to int and set to 0 if null. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use logical 'or' operator (see [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)),

```
parseInt('10') || 0; // give 10
parseInt('') || 0; // give 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the value is a number by [isNaN()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) function and then perform summation.

Answer (score 0):

use `isNaN()`, put it in an if statement, if true, set the variable to 0

```
if(isNaN(yourVar)) {
    yourVar = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator will work just fine

```
yourVar = (isNaN(yourVar)) ? 0 : yourVar
```

So if you want to check if your textbox value is empty or not, you can use:

```
val = your_textbox_value == '' ? 0 : your_textbox_value
```

Answer (score 0):

assign that object to it this will work fine

```
you_object = you_object == null ? "0" : you_object;
```